# changing text color for android app

Tags: android, clock, textcolor

I currently have an app that displays the time. I want to change the text to white so i have

```
<DigitalClock android:textColor = "@androidcolor/white">
```

for some reason when i put this line in the XML code, my Graphical layout shows the time white but i get an error saying "Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'textColor' with value '@androidcolor/white"

Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant to write `@android:color/white`?

Comment: wow that colon was it ... the tutorial i was looking had a typo -- I should send him a comment letting him know.. THanks!

Comment: srry I didnt check mark it earlier